# kendo data source group

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

We are trying to basically and literally group data in a data source like you can do with SQL when selecting against a table.

So I get data that looks like the following:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"4", f5:"5", f6: "1"},
            {f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"4", f5:"5", f6: "3"},
            {f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"6", f5:"7", f6: "2"},
            {f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"6", f5:"7", f6: "1"},
            {f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"6", f5:"5", f6: "2"}
        ]},
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

We want to group by f1, f2, f3, f4 and sum on f6.

The result when we show this data in a grid or list view should be that the data source has only 2 rows in it

```
{f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"4", sum: "4"},
{f1: "1", f2:"2", f3:"3", f4:"6", sum: "5"},
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The dataSource has a group property that can be used to add a collection of groups.

Comment: If you are already done with [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-group) doc, then provide some workarounds so that others can figure out what actually the problem is.

Comment: As far as I understand what @ShawnBiggr is looking for is what groups and aggregates can do but the question is that in a Grid, they show a handler that allows to expand the data that is grouped and I'm not sure that this is what he wants.
As far as I can see, he will have to do some pre-processing of the original DataSource creating one that has the group/aggregates.